# Using Swagger for documenting RESTful services in Mule

Tags: mule, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to use swagger for documenting our RESTful APIs. Our Jersey classes will be consumed from the mule flow. To use swagger for documenting my API I need to use the servlet configuration as mentioned in here - https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart

As the Jersey classes are deployed in mule, there is no web.XML.

If you know how to configure swagger with Mule please let me know how to do that. I truly appreciate your feedback and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible options, the latter being the one with the highest chance of success:

- Run a Servlet container inside Mule, as demonstrated by the bookstore example provided with the standalone distribution, configuring web.xml as indicated and making sure you're using `servlet` not `http` inbound endpoints in your Mule configuration.
- Generate at build time a static Swagger configuration using https://github.com/ryankennedy/swagger-jaxrs-doclet and serve it using the static resource message processor from the HTTP transport.

Comment: Has anybody been successful with those? I got the swagger-jaxrs-doclet running, but it is not clear, in the wiki, that it could serve static files. Instead, it publishes a python webserver serving the docs. Are you suggesting that we can just save the output of service.json and serve it statically?

Comment: The approach I took was to add the swagger configuration and serve it through a generic resource "docs".